# Dual of holomorphic functions (with the $L^1$ topology)

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

Let $\Omega$ be a connected domain of the complex plane, and let $E$ be the vector space of integrable holomorphic functions on $\Omega$. Then it can be checked that $E$ is a closed subspace of $L^1(\Omega)$. My question (which I'm sure has a well-known answer, but I couldn't find it) is : what is the dual of $E$ ? More precisely, does it identify with a nice (i.e. explicit) subspace of $L^\infty(\Omega)$ ?

Note that since we do not endow $E$ with the usual topology of holomorphic functions (uniform convergence on compacts) this has a priori nothing to do with hyperfunctions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key term is [Bergman space](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bergman_spaces). The space you introduced is usually denoted  $A^1(\Omega)$ or $L^1_a(\Omega)$. When $\Omega$ is a disk, the dual of $A^1(\Omega)$ can be identified with the space of Bloch functions on the disk. This is proved in the book *Bergman spaces* by Duren and Schuster. (By the way, in the reflexive range $1<p<\infty$ we have $(A^p)^*=A^q$ on the disk, with $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$.)

If $\Omega$ is simply-connected and has smooth boundary ($C^{1,\alpha}$ with $\alpha>0$), then the conformal map of $\Omega$ onto the disk has derivative bounded from $0$ and $\infty$. By the change of variable formula, the map induces isomorphism between Bergman spaces on $\Omega$ and on the disk. Thus,   the problem reduces to the case of the disk; the dual is again the Bloch space.

For a general simply-connected domain $\Omega$, the identification of the dual of $A^p(\Omega)$ is difficult; it is related to a major open problem in complex function theory (Brennan's conjecture). As a starting point, see the paper [The dual of a Bergman space on simply connected domains](http://www.math.kth.se/~haakanh/publications/hedenmalm-jam2.pdf) by Hedenmalm.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. in the paper you cite it seems they only treat the case $4/3 \leq p \leq 4$. do you know any result concerning the case $p=1$ for, say, an annulus of finite modulus (that's  the case I'm especially interested in) ? or is it still open ? anyway thanks again, and I'll look into it.

Comment: @Melchior My guess is: the dual is the version of Bloch space for the annulus, i.e., holomorphic functions $f$ such that $\mathrm{dist}\,(z,\partial \Omega)|f'(z)|$ is bounded in $\Omega$. The duality would be $\int \bar f g$ for $g\in A^1$ (the integral need not be absolutely convergent). My second guess is: this is not proved anywhere in the literature. You could try to extend the proof in Duren&Schuster to the case of annulus, using Laurent series instead of Taylor series. Failing that, ask Hedenmalm or Schuster.

Comment: thank you very much ! I'll look at the proof of Duren and Schuster.